# How can I make defined name globally available?

Tags: php, class, global-variables, global

I have a file which defines a name like this.

`<root>/dir1/dir2/file1.php`

```
//directory indicator
define("DI", "../../");

//adding required files
require_once DI . 'lib/Config.php';
require_once DI . 'lib/Common.php';
```

This adds `Config.php` and `Common.php` correctly.

Now when I try to get `DI` in `Config.php` like this

`<root>/Config.php`

```
<?php
class Config
{
   public $value = DI . 'some_value';
}
```

I cant get that value there.

How can I make `DI` available inside `Config` class ?

### EDIT

Real Folder Hierarchy

```
ROOT--> somefile.php
|__ lib --> config.php
|
|___ dir1
     |
     |__  dir2  
          |
          |__ file1.php
```

I need to get root directory inside the class that is defined in config.php. that is I need to include `somefile.php` from `config.php`. I know I can do this simply like

```
 include '../somefile.php';
```

But the problem is config.php holds a class which contains `static` methods. So I can get those methods like this.

```
  Config::MethodInsideConfig();
```

Now when I try this from `file1.php`, it seems that `../somefile.php` is trying to include from `dir1`. I think php uses `file1.php`'s location for calculating the preceding directory. But what I need is it should get the file from root directory.

Comment: You can't yet define a constant value in a class that's dependent on run-time information

Comment: @MarkBaker : edited question. The point is I need to get `DI` inside `Config` class

Comment: Inject the value as an argument into your class `__construct()`, and set the property in your constructor

Comment: @MarkBaker : how can I get `DI` in constructor then ? I cannot manually define that value in that class. Depend upon the value that I specified in `file1.php`, all class should use that `DI`

Comment: I think you're confusing `abstract` with `static`

Comment: @MarkBaker : Good catch. Yes they are not abstract methods. They are static methods

Comment: Then create a static setter method that you can call to set the value, passing in the DI value to that, as soon as you've determined the value of DI

Answer (score 0):

Inject the value as an argument into your class __construct(), and set the property in your constructor

```
class Config
{
    public $value;

    public __construct($di) {
        $this->value = $di . 'some_value';
    }
}

$myConfig = new Config(DI);
```

Comment: how can I get `DI` in constructor then ? I cannot manually define that value in that class. Depend upon the value that I specified in file1.php, all class should use that `DI`

Comment: The example I posted should demonstrate exactly how to get the value of DI into your constructor, and use it to set the $value property

Comment: oh got it. Let me allow to shot this.

Comment: I forgot. Unfortunately `Config` is an abstract class.!

Comment: In that case, you surely have concrete classes that extend Config.... inject DI into their constructors, and make sure that they call `parent::__construct($di);`

Comment: Config and Common classes are intend to use as very basic classes. Can  I use `__DIR__` inside `config` class in order to direct to directory position which comes just before its current position. I have tried `'../'.__DIR__`. however didnt work

Comment: If you're trying to use `'../'.__DIR__` to set a property directly, then no you can't, concatenation is a run-time operation

Comment: no I have tried `include '../'.__DIR__.'somefile.php'`. where somefile.php resides in the directory where the parent directory of config.php resides.

Comment: Well I really don't have a clue what your system and your classes look like now, or what you're trying to so. With just a few additional comments that you've made, it's evolved quite drastically from the simple question that you posted, and to which I posted an answer

Comment: see my edit. I hope now everythings become more clear

Answer (score 0):

Why defining new constant PHP already has predefined constante [**DIR**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) it's contain the current file directory.

So, your requires will be like this :

```html
//adding required files
require_once __DIR__.'/../../'. '/lib/Config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../../'. 'lib/Common.php';
```

- USING INI FILE

You can use config file (like config.ini)

```html
[parameteres]
path_app_root="/usr/share/apache/www/my_app";
```

Then, your config as singleton class will be used to parse ini file and get config

```html
<?php
class Config
{
 public $configs = array();
 private static $instance;
 
 private function __construct() {}

 public static function getInstance()
 {
  if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
   $c = __CLASS__;
   self::$instance = new $c;
   self::$instance->configs = parse_ini_file(__DIR__."/../config.ini");
  }

  return self::$instance;
 }

 public function getRootPath()
 {
  
  return self::$instance->configs['path_app_root'];
 }

    public function __clone()
    {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Your file1.php will be like this

```html
<?php
//adding required files
require_once '../../lib/Config.php';

echo Config::getInstance()->getRootPath();
```

Anas

Comment: I need to go to root location from config class. I have tried `'../'.__DIR__`. didnt work. Is that correct?

Comment: can you post your files folders & files hierarchy ?

Comment: And why you need to the root directory from Config class ? Config.php should be a lib file so it will be included on your script without depending on root directory

Comment: see " USING INI FILE "
I think that's you must rethink your file structure.
So Config.php must be in root directory and if you see my example, you can init your configs from config.ini file
Then, you can use the Singleton (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) config class to access to all your app shared parameters.
By using config.ini, you can easily manage your app settings